# Finding child of previous sibling in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I am modifying existing code, so I can only affect the elements that exist rather an building it right. I am iterating over all `spans` that have the class **reqd**, and if so, I'm either taking the immediate previous sibling (example 1) or the previous sibling's first child of type input (example 2) and appending jQuery validate attributes to it.

Using `prev()` was for example #1, which was easy. I have to use `prevUntil()` for examples 2 and 3 to isolate better where I am targeting the DOM.

My issue is with example #2. While I can reach `class="regfieldlabel` I cannot get it to traverse its children. Example #3 is like #2 except with an empty span tag in the middle.

```
//Example code 1
<input type="text" name="str_cvv" value="" maxlength="3" size="4" id="CVV">
<span class="reqd">*</span>

//Example code 2
<span class="regfieldlabel">
      <input type="text" name="nameOnCard" size="30" maxlength="50" id="cardName" value="">
</span>
<span class="reqd">*</span>

//Example code 3
<span class="regfieldlabel">
      <input type="text" name="nameOnCard" size="30" maxlength="50" id="cardName" value="">
</span>
<span class="regfieldlabel"> </span>
<span class="reqd">*</span>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("span").each(function(){
        //Highlight all fields that have a red asterisk at the end for validation
        if ($(this).hasClass('reqd')) {
            $(this).prev().attr('data-rule-required', true).attr('data-msg-required', 'This field is required');
            $(this).prevUntil('.regfieldlabel').find('input').attr('data-rule-required', true).attr('data-msg-required', 'This field is required');

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is the code not just doing `$("span.reqd").each(` from the start?

Comment: I don't know why, because you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `prevUntil`, from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) you will see:

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element up to **but not
>   including the element matched by the selector**, DOM node, or jQuery
>   object.

As a result, `$(this).prevUntil('.regfieldlabel')` is actually empty.

For Example 2, you still want to use just `prev`:

```
$(this).prev('.regfieldlabel').find('input')
```

---

For a general solution, you will have to check which situation you are in, in order to do the correct thing:

```
$("span.reqd").each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var $prev = $this.prev();
    var $input = $([]); // init to empty

    if($prev.is("input")){
        // EXAMPLE 1
        $input = $prev;

    } else if($prev.is(".regfieldlabel")){
        var $innerInput = $prev.find("input");

        if($innerInput.length > 0){
            // EXAMPLE 2
            $input = $innerInput;
        } else {
            $prev = $prev.prev(".regfieldlabel");
            $innerInput = $prev.find("input");

            if($innerInput.length > 0){
                // EXAMPLE 3
                $input = $innerInput;
            } else {
                // unknown case, maybe do something here
            }
        }
    } else {
        // unknown case, maybe do something here
    }

    $input.attr('data-rule-required', true).attr('data-msg-required', 'This field is required');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DVSeg/2/

Comment: @epascarello is right. inspect element is showing me it appends the data attributes to parent `span.regfieldlabel`.

Comment: The question stated "My issue is with example #2" so I didn't address example 3.  I will update with example 3.

Comment: @AngrySpartan Updated with general solution including working example.

Comment: Wonderful job! So wonderful the other submitted answer went incognito, apparently.